# How to update a playermodel?

Tags: garrys-mod

i'm looking for change the LocalPlayer() playermodel with a function. I'm using LocalPlayer():SetModel() it's look like it's working because the player model is like updating and re updating to the last playermodel.
Have you got an idea to update it manually or disable the suffled playermodel of the job?
I'm in darkRP

Comment: It might be worth asking through DarkRP support, since this question is specific to that gamemode.
You can find a link to their Discord on the repo - https://github.com/FPtje/DarkRP

Answer (score 0):

LocalPlayer() refers to the client who the code runs for, and is entirely clientside. If it's working, but then changing back, there is likely some code running that is syncing the client model to the serverside model.

You should instead try to update the player model serverside.